# Javascript maptiler wont work but latitude and longitude show up

Tags: javascript, html, maptiler

I am trying to get the users current position to show up in a map using maptiler, however I seem to be able to get the longitude and latitude to show up in text but not on the map... what am I not seeing or getting here? it shows the right location.... if only I could get it into the map!

```js
 <script>
//plug in coordinated generated my below code
    var coordsArray = [];
var x = document.getElementById("map");
//generate coordinates to plug into map
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
//coordinates to put into map
function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
        //Creates the map object with the intended coordinates and sets zoom level to 14
        var map = L.map('map').setView(coordsArray, 14);
        //Creates the required WebGL metadata and chains it to the map object
        var gl = L.mapboxGL({
            attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">© MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
            accessToken: 'not-needed',
            style: 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/style.json?key=qZjWTwtNTmBxDi3ZpTB5'
        }).addTo(map);
        //Creates the marker for the intended coordinates and chains it to the map object 
      var marker = L.marker(coordsArray).addTo(map);
    </script>
```

```css
        #map {
            min-height:300px;
            width:600px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
  <p>Click on hte button to see where you are on a map!</p>
  <button onclick="getLocation()">Show me where I am</button>
  <div id="map"></div>
      <p><a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">© MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a></p>
  
  </div>

</body>
```